# On Chrome 49, component including link field cannot be saved

Tags: cme, component, browser

On Tridion 2013 SP1 and 2011 SP1, after I upgraded Google Chrome browser version to 49.0.2623.75, a component which includes component link or multimedia link field cannot be saved.

When creating a new component, I selected a linked component at component link field and click 'save and close' button.
Then the component wasn't saved and following error occured

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'console' of null

[image]

Does anyone know same problem?
Is it possible to avoid this problem by changing browser setting, or is it a Tridion's defect?

Regards,

Comment: We're looking at it. As soon as we understand what did Google break, we'll fix it. This also affects Web 8.

Comment: And to answer your 2nd question: if it works in every other browser, and in the previous versions of Chrome, it's probably _not_ a Tridion defect. Chrome introduces breaking issues quite regularly, in Chrome 36 (or around that) they had a similar issue that got fixed a couple of versions later.

Comment: Hofixes available now

Comment: Please refer below Answer
http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/on-chrome-49-still-cannot-save-components-in-tridion-2013-after-applying-hotfix

Answer (score 5):

Lots of users including me facing issue with mentioned version of chrome.

Hot Fixes available now. Login to [SDL Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/) required before downloading.

SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2: [Hotfix CME_2011.1.2.1673](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CME_2011.1.2.1673_tcm89-21677.zip)

SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1: [Hotfix CME_2013.1.1.1673](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CME_2013.1.1.1673_tcm89-21676.zip) (Updated version available now)

Comment: The above Hotfix Hotfix CME_2013.1.1.1673 is not working for chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 .

Comment: working for me in above browser in 2013 sp1 hr1, , make sure you updated sytem.config and try clearing your browser cache

Comment: earlier version which i installed has only tree.js it worked for me. i think now it has been updated without even changing the version name :( try it now.

Comment: There were two versions of the hotfix released, the first version only tree.js file was included and in next version (with the same hotfix number) it included two files: tree.js and FormatArea.js. it is working post apply latest version with FormatArea.js and tree.js

Comment: @Rameshponna yes you are right and that's what i wrote in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue to SDL. I understand they are working on a fix ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If your copy of Chrome hasn't already updated itself, this may help:

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates