# On Chrome 49, still cannot save components in Tridion 2013 after applying Hotfix 1673

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, chrome

Even after applying hotfix 1673 to Tridion 2013 SP1 (replacing Tree.js and incrementing the "modification" value in System.config), users on Chrome 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) cannot save components. Users clearing their browser cache does not seem to make a difference. The users who have reported the issue so far were using Macs.

The error message in the console is different than what was reported [in a similar question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/on-chrome-49-component-including-link-field-cannot-be-saved/) prior to the hotfix:
[image: Chrome Screen Capture post Hotfix]

Does the hotfix not address this particular version of Chrome? Or is there another step I should be taking to ensure the hotfix is applied?

Comment: Just a note that if you have an issue with a hotfix, you're probably better off just contacting customer support.

Comment: One more update to hotfix released today so again update it.

Comment: @PeterKjaer ok, will do next time we have an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mark - There were two versions of the hotfix released, the first version only tree.js file was included and in next version (with the same hotfix number) it included two files: tree.js and FormatArea.js.

So make sure that you have applied the later version of the hotfix containing two files and also version number is incremented in system.config.

Comment: Thanks! I was using a version of the hotfix from yesterday that did not include the updated FormatArea.js. With the updated Tree.js and FormatArea.js Tridion seems to be working in all versions of Chrome.

Comment: Yes with both js version the issue is resolved.