# BluePrint unable to 'Create New Child' publication in Chrome

Tags: blueprint, 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion, chrome

I am unable to create a new child publication in our *existing* `BluePrint`.

I have experienced this previously (approx 1 week ago), and went on the server through `localhost` and was able to create that way, and now it looks as though I cannot create in either client browser or on the server.

[image]

I have isolated that this is only happening on my Chrome browser `Version 49.0.2623.87 m`

[image]

I have not been able to find much info on this, probably another reason I am creating a post. Please see screen shots above and version.

Anyone else experience the same?

Comment: Grrr *!@#$@!*()%! Google. Probably related to the breaking changes in chrome 49. It worked when you went on the server probably because Chrome wasn't updated yet. After you used it it updated to #49, and now it's broken. I'll ask our Dev to look at it. Did you apply the hotfix? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/on-chrome-49-still-cannot-save-components-in-tridion-2013-after-applying-hotfix

Comment: Yes, Last week as well. Also checked other environments that hasnt had that hotfix applied to yet - same issue. Works in IE 11 & FF as expected.

Comment: It looks like we can't reproduce this in house. Have you applied the updated hotfix? There was an issue with the first version we pushed out, it wasn't complete.

Comment: Okay. Let me go back and double-check the emails and download the latest to ensure I have correct patch.

Comment: @NunoLinhares Okay. Got the correct patch. It's working correctly.