# Tridion chrome 49 multimedia link save issue patch is not downloadable showing access forbidden

Tags: 2011

We are having issue while saving the multimedia component in tridion on chrome 49 version. The issue resoluiton is given at link [On Chrome 49, component including link field cannot be saved](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/on-chrome-49-component-including-link-field-cannot-be-saved?lq=1) but I am not able to download the 2011 related patch it is showing the access forbidden error, please help me by telling me how can i download this.

Specically I am getting the error in attached screenshot when trying to add an multimedia component in the chrome 49 browser[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be logged in to the SDL Tridion World site before you can download hotfixes. If you log in first, then go to the link it should work fine, if you do not have an account contact customer support.